# Multithreaded Search using c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to seach more than 15000 values in a select statement as shown below:

`select * from tableA where id in (1,2,3......16000)`

Can I use threads, say around 3, and partion 15000 values in diffrent select statement.

1. `select * from tableA where id in (1,2,3......5000)`
2. `select * from tableA where id in (5001....10000)`
3. `select * from tableA where id in (10001....15000)`

and run these 3 select statment in parallel.

Comment: It might help if you included what db you're using

Comment: You technically could do this but unless your intent is to process the data in chunks as well it wouldn't help you much.  The actual data pull itself will be run more efficiently as one pull than as multiple. If it is the case that you need to process the data in chunks I would pull the data first then split it up client side rather than trying to pull it as separate sets from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the real question is why?

Something like this might get you started:

```
var itms = new List<YourDataClass>();

var thr1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
{
    // select code
    // populate itms
}));
var thr2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
{
    // select code
    // populate itms
}));
var thr3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
{
    // select code
    // populate itms
}));

thr1.Start();
thr2.Start();
thr3.Start();
```

However, that said, if your IDs are integers and (based on your sample) the range of `IN` values are sequential, you might want to switch to a `where id > 1 and id < 16000` style. This may yeild better performance.

Comment: ids are not sequential and may or may not be intrger

Comment: Understood, the sample data in your question made it seem like they might be.

Answer (score 1):

You may tried the parallel programming feature of C# 4.0

It's rather simple:

```
List<String> jobs = new List<String>();
Parallel.ForEach(jobs, job=>
    {
        Foo(job);
    }
);
```

Have a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is possible and may even be a good idea since sending a (very) large `IN` statement to a database may result in errors.

Your database should handle your parallel queries correctly and without problems.